# Javafx List<Data<Number,Number>> removeAll didn't work

Tags: java, list, javafx, arraylist, removeall

I have this :

```
List<Data<Number, Number>> dataList = new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number,Number>>();
List<Data<Number, Number>> dataListSelected = new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number,Number>>();
```

I fill them with some Data<Number,Number> (in reality it is some Double). I do this for the two list.

```
        for (XYZPointModel xyz : pm.getTopoPoints()) {
            topoPoints.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(xyz.getX(),xyz.getY()));
        }
```

and then i compare the two list. I want to know if i have some data in dataList that i dont have in dataListSelected.

```
System.out.println(dataList.removeAll(dataListSelected));
```

I got a FALSE.
Here the containt of my 2 list :

*3 : [Data[18.367963,-0.832832,null], Data[30.165189,-0.461874,null], Data[18.808959,-6.575699,null]]*

*3 : [Data[18.367963,-0.832832,null], Data[30.165189,-0.461874,null], Data[18.808959,-6.575699,null]]*

Btw, i don't know why i have a double, double, null. I dont know where the null come from.
Why my removeAll don't work ?

Comment: fx is open source - implying that the source is readable :) So if you don't understand any particular output, reading the implementation of toString will help to answer your add-on question (in this case, reading the java doc should give you at least a hint as to where the null might come from ;)

Answer (score 1):

I presume Data is actually JavaFX.XYChart.Data, which has another object node as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#toString--). Therefore, this is null. I do not know if the "toString" method prints the value of the node object, but it sure seems like it.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList (and many other collections) use the contains() (which uses equals() method) to determine whether to remove an object in the remove()/removeAll() methods. if you check the following condition:

```
dataList.get(0).equals(dataListSelected.get(0))
```

my guess is it would be false, and therefore removeAll fails as well.

Comment: Yes it return false. But why ? The two objects are supposed to be same value.

Comment: it depends on the implementation of equals() in the object XYChart.Data<Number,Number>, if they implemented it at all...

Comment: _Yes it return false. But why ?_ That's plain java, unrelated to fx: the default implementation of equals is identity - please work through a tutorial on language basics!

Answer (score 0):

1、ArrayList use equals() to remove,

```
if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
```

but XYChart.Data didn't override equals() method, so Data will use method of Object

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

2、XYChart.Data has three properties

```
X xValue, Y yValue, Object extraValue
```

double, double, null